# DIV elements on both sides of a page have spaces in between each other

Tags: css, html, css-float

I would like to create two columns of div elements, one floating on the left and one on the right.  I expect all the left ones to stack on top of each other and the same for the right ones.  However I am seeing spaces between the divs in the right hand column that seem to come from the heights on the left one.  How can I lay this out with no spaces in between?  Example is http://jsfiddle.net/acugV/

```
<style type="text/css">
div {
    width: 50px;
    outline: 1px dashed #666
}
.left {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    background: yellow
}
.right {
    float: right;
    clear: right;
    background: #0f0
}
</style>
<div class="left" style="height:75px"></div>
<div class="right" style="height:50px"></div>
<div class="left" style="height:50px"></div>
<div class="right" style="height:50px"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to create a container around the divs that floats, instead of floating each container on it's own.

```
<div class="left">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
</div>
<div class="right">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/acugV/5/

Comment: The reason I think this won't work for me is that the divs on each side will have different widths.  That is, I am trying to make ragged margins on each side for the text to flow between.  Some of the divs have 0 width to act as "spacers".  If I put them all into a big div then I will lose the raggedness.

Comment: You can still define a width attribute while still using the wrapping divs. The outer div just has to be as big as the biggest div. I updated the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/acugV/6/

Comment: But when you add body text, it fills the region left by the outer divs.  http://jsfiddle.net/acugV/7 ...  I would like the text to follow the ragged margin, sort of like this: http://jsfiddle.net/acugV/8 (except that parts of this look weird too)